# Python get ffmpeg process

Tags: python, tkinter, video, ffmpeg

I am working on my own video editing software. But when the users clicks render I want to show a progress bar so the user knows how long they have to wait. How do I get the progress of ffmpeg because I use that for rendering their videos. The complete software is written in Python tkinter.

Comment: have a look at https://pypi.org/project/python-ffmpeg/ which does give events as ffmpeg executes - might give you some of what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. To do so you would have to rewrite the FFmpeg. I would recommend updating a progress bar after some commands got executed. For example

```
response = session.get(link, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=True)

self.progress_50 = Label(self.root, bd = 0, bg = '#1A1A1A', image =self.progress_50_photo)
self.progress_50.place(x=100, y=400)
self.root.update()
for i in akol:
    some_code
self.progress_100=Label(self.root,bd=0,bg='#1A1A1A',image=self.progress_100_phot)
self.progress_100.place(x=100, y=400)
self.root.update()
```

Comment: @Kevin29890 can you then upvote my comment and accept my answer please? :)

Comment: Ilkleiw I upvoted your comment and accepted as the correct answer but you cant see my upvote becouse i do not have that much points